# can Go's http server compile typescript?

Tags: go, typescript, angular

Currently I have a NodeJS Application that starts an http server with client side code that is written in TypeScript and using Angular 2.

is it possible to do the same in Go ?

I tried googling for TypeScript and Go and didn't find anything relevant.

should I have nodeJS installed, install typescript compiler with `npm install -g typescript`, compile the typescripts whenever I change them and provide the javascript files on my Go Server ?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: I've looked into this in the past, and I find it's just easier to combine a `http.FileServer` with `tsc -w` that will automatically compile the files and dump them to the static folder. That way the Go code doesn't have to worry about compile errors, new versions, etc.

Comment: @robbrit I'll look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

1. Do the translation client side by including the typescript library in your html and loading `<script type='text/typescript' src="/myscript.ts"></script>`
2. Run `tsc -w` in the background and just serve the compiled javascript. You could launch it when your app starts so it dies with your app as well. I only run tsc in "dev" mode, and check in the js files for production use.
3. Run tsc on demand when you receive requests, and cache results. Probably pretty tricky to detect changes but there are [packages](https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify) to help with that.

Comment: You could also now [build a handler](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild) to compile TS on the fly.